# How i can use colors from vuetify config in my custom scss file?

Tags: sass, colors, vuetify.js

i need some littlle help, and understand correctly how i can work with a theme.
This is my vuetify config

```
//plugins/vuetify.ts

export const GalaxyLightTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    primary: "#9C27B0",
  },
}
```

Now i would like use my primary colors in my main.scss and i dont know how :frowning:

```
@use 'vuetify/lib/styles/main' with (
  $body-font-family: 'Open Sans'
);

.my-custom-class {
  color: var(--v-primary-base);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@use 'vuetify/lib/styles/main' with (
  $body-font-family: 'Open Sans'
);

.my-custom-class {
  color: rgb(var(--v-theme-primary))
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?